# Meaning of "using 10-dollar words to describe 10-cent ideas"

Tags: meaning, phrases

I came across the phrase "If you enjoy using 10-dollar words to describe 10-cent ideas,... " , but I am not sure what it means, specifically when related to Hindi. Do we have a similar expression in Hindi to clarify the meaning of this phrase?

Comment: I don't know.  What's the question about English?  The idiom is pejorative like *pedantic* or *bloviate*.

Comment: It is a variation on the expression discussed here:

http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45683/value-in-cents-of-big-words

Comment: This site is about English, not Hindi.

Comment: related:[Should I use 10 cent words or $2 words?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24729/should-i-use-10-cent-words-or-2-words)

Comment: It's another way of saying using sesquipedalian words.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Please read the title "Meaning of “using 10-dollar words to describe 10-cent ideas” ". You try to say in English don't have meanings? right that I asked. and queried if there is related idiom.

Answer (score 2):

I would hazard the guess that this means using fancy, learned or literary words out of context and, consequently, you might not be taken seriously. E.g. you could replace "I'm going to bed in a minute" by "I shall retire into Morpheus' arms shortly". Said once, it might be funny (depending on the context), used regularly, it would sound pompous.